# jquery live firing more than once for the same event and element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a generic pagination utility, a very simplified form is this:

```
Pagin = function(settings){

    var prevSelector = settings.prevSelector || 'a[title="Previous"]',
    nextSelector = settings.nextSelector || 'a[title="Next"]';

    $(prevSelector).live('click', onPrevNextPage);
    $(nextSelector).live('click', onPrevNextPage);
}
```

There more than a couple of places in the same place that needs pagination. I am trying to reuse it by creating different objects like this:

```
var gridPagin = new Pagin();
var dialogPagin = new Pagin();
```

The problem I am facing is, after having 2 objects, clicking on 'prev' or 'next' the function onPrevNextPage is executed twice.

Is there a way to tell live to trigger only once even though the handler is attached twice?

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detach the previous handler first:

```
$(prevSelector).die('click').live('click', onPrevNextPage);
```